# start fragment on actionbar icon click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I want to open a fragment when an activity's actionbar icon is clicked and remove the fragment (and go back to activity) when back button (in fragment's layout) is clicked. The imp thing is there is no `<fragment>` in my activity layout.

```css
main activity layout

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is main activity layout"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        
</LinearLayout>
```

```html
MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
   
 }
 
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  
  case R.id.settings:
   newintent();

  default:
   break;
  }
  
  return true;
  
 }

 private void newintent() {
  
  
  // Do something here to open FragmentOne.class
  
 }

 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a fragment and add this code in your click event method

```
private Fragment newFragment=new NewFragment();//global variable

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        FragmentTransaction ft =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.current_layout, newFragment,"Order");
ft.commit();
```

you can follow this link .. [click](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-fragments-to-an-activity-in-android/)

Comment: I tried that. For this we need add a <fragment> in the activity layout and I don't want to add any fragment as there will be many things in my layout. @Tanim.

Comment: add a <fragment> in the activity layout  what is the meaning of this... you dont need to add anything in your main activity...  totally different layout file will  create when you create a newFragment...

Comment: @SomnathPal  Do you mean something which covers partially the screen? Fragment is portion of activity which can be hosted in a base activity. This base activity can have more than one fragment. I think your question needs more explanation...!!!

Comment: @SomnathPal You don't need to add a `<fragment>` element to your layout file: Tanim's method is for a dynamic `Fragment`. You will however need to assign an `id` attribute to your root layout (`LinearLayout` in this case) to replace `R.id.order_navigation_frameLayout` in this example - or you could use `android.R.id.content`

Comment: I want Instagram like settings which they have in Profile page. There when you click on the settings icon, a new layout will open but it will not cover the bottom navigation tabs. I want to make same action.

Comment: Hey Tanim. Your code is working perfectly after adding the root layout's id. Though I would like to thank PPartisan for his suggestion of course. @Tanimreja

Comment: Finally, in Studio there is a back button in the actionbar. On clicking the back button will it remove the fragment page? @Tanimreja. Thanks again for your answer and support.

Comment: back button will remove fragment from stack. if not then there is another method